# Mismatch between tileserver-gl version and Openmaptiles.com map data?

Tags: openmaptiles

We're paid subscribers of Openmaptiles.com production map package and we're setting up a new version of latest Docker version of tileserver-gl (v2.6.0) with the latest map data from Openmaptiles.com (osm-2019-07-01-v3.10-europe_spain.mbtiles) and we've got an error message:

```
# docker run -it -v --restart=always -p 80:80 -v /var/lib/docker/tileserver-gl/data/osm:/data --network tileserver-gl-net --ip 172.18.0.3 --name tileserver-gl_osm_v2.6.0 klokantech/tileserver-gl:v2.6.0 --verbose
Starting Xvfb on display 99
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":99".
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":99".

Starting tileserver-gl v2.6.0
No MBTiles specified, using osm-2019-07-01-v3.10-europe_spain.mbtiles
Automatically creating config file for osm-2019-07-01-v3.10-europe_spain.mbtiles
ERROR: Metadata missing in the MBTiles.
       Make sure osm-2019-07-01-v3.10-europe_spain.mbtiles is valid MBTiles.
```

We have tested two Docker versions of tileserver-gl, v2.3.1 and v2.6.0, with old map data from Openmaptiles.com, osm-2018-05-13-v3.8-europe_spain.mbtiles for example, and everything works fine. We have downloaded map data two times just to check if first downloaded map data file was corrupt. What are we doing wrong?
We also miss a compatibility matrix that enables Openmaptiles subscribers to match tileserver-gl versions with Openmaptiles.com map data versions, as well as the ability to download updated map data for other Openmaptiles.com map versions than the latest, just to overcome these incompatibilities.
Best regards,
Santiago

Comment: You might want to try just opening mbtiles files in SQLite editor and change version to 3 (3.8?) in metadata and see if server will it pick it up, it did trick for me for some maps.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is very probably corrupted or not downloaded correctly.

You can verify its MD5 hash sum, using `md5sum <filename>`, which has to correspond with MD5 value on the webpage - https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/osm/europe/spain/

We recommend to download with `wget -c <link>`.

Comment: We've checked that MD5 hash sum match, so we can assume file is not corrupted.

Comment: Tested with new Openmaptiles.com map data (osm-2019-07-01-v3.10-europe_spain.mbtiles), hash sum matches and continues failing

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience.
It was a file permissions issue.